# How do I center the placeholder and text inside the search input, properly?

Tags: html, css, search, placeholder

I wanted to ask how would I properly centre align the placeholder in my case 'Search' and the actual text when the user inputs characters inside this search box, properly?
Thank you very much for your help, in advance.

Here is my html:

```
<form action="http://wordpress1.brighter-software.co.uk" id="searchform" method="get" class="cf">
   <fieldset style="border:none; margin:0; padding:0;">
      <input type="search" id="search-field" class="cf" name="s" placeholder="Search" required="">
      <input type="image" id="search-submit" class="cf" alt="Search" src="http://wordpress1.brighter-software.co.uk/wp-content/themes/201/images/search-icon.png">
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
/*
=====================
Search Bar
===================== */
#searchform {
  float:right;
  border:none;
  margin-right:40px;
  background-color:#272727;
}
#searchform input[type="search"]:focus {
  outline:none;
}
#search-field {
  float:right;
  background-color: #272727;
  border: none;
  width:80%;
  line-height:3;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:right;
  color:#FFF;
}
#search-submit {
  float:left;
  width:50px;
}
::-Webkit-input-placeholder { /* For WebKit browsers */
  direction: rtl;
  color:white;
  font-size:1.3em;

}
::-moz-placeholder { /* For Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  direction: rtl;
  color:white;
  font-size:1.3em;

}
::-moz-placeholder { /* For Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  direction: rtl;
  color:white;
  font-size:1.3em;

}
::-ms-input-placeholder { /* For Internet Explorer 10+ */
  direction: rtl;
  color:white;
  font-size:1.3em;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XT8JA/ Is this what you're after?

Comment: Thank you to all for helping! -Solved-

Comment: @user3744106 If one of the answers worked for you to solve your problem, it would be kind to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you want to center the text (and placeholder) in the `<input type="search" ... >`. Just change the `text-align:right;` of the `#search-field` selector to `text-align:center;`:

```
#search-field {
  float:right;
  background-color: #272727;
  border: none;
  width:80%;
  line-height:3;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FFF;
}
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7CsP/)**.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/UU6YJ/)

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
  text-align:center;
  color: red;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  text-align:center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
  text-align:center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
  text-align:center; 
}
```